# Padding spaces in excel 2016

Tags: excel-2016

Is there a way to pad spaces in excel 2016?

I have two columns, I want to concatenate the two fields with spaces between the values align.

My results:

```
id  last           NewColumn
1   Smith          1 = Smith
2   CoppHeadlager  2 =    CoppHeadlager
```

My expect results. The spacing between the columns align, how can I do this?

```
id  last              New column
1   Smith             1   =  Smith
2   CoppHeadlager     2   =  CoppHeadlager
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
= text(A:A,"00") & " = " & trim(B:B)
```